# Select multiple columns from two tables using greendao

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite, greendao

I have two tables A and B and I want to write the following query using greendao.

```
select a.*, b.* from A a, B b where a.a_id=b.a_id;
```

I have achieved so far:

```
Adao.queryRawCreate(" , B b where T.a_id=b.a_id");
```

But this will return only rows from A. I need the columns from A and B both.
How can i achieve this using greendao?

Comment: What kind of Join do you want ? Cross join, Inner, Left ?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev, the example query is an inner join.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev It's an inner join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greendao doesn't support joins yet.

Even if it would: greendao is an ORM-framework. This means it maps your table-rows to object. With an ORM-framework you generally traverse from object to object using the toMany and toOne relations and you don't request multiple rows to be mapped to one object.

For your problem this means you should get your desired entities of A.

If you need the corresponding B-entities you can access them through A. To be able to do so you have to specify a toMany or toOne relation between A and B (depending on your datamodel).