# How to do a "select customer.name, count(order._id) ..." from joined tables in greenDAO

Tags: sql, android-sqlite, greendao

I would like to do a query such as the following:

```
    select customers.name, count(orders._id) 
    from customers, orders 
    where customers._id = orders.customer_id
```

So that I can get the customer name and how many orders they have.

Can this be done with a greenDAO querybuilder (preferred) or will I have to do it with a standard database query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with greenDAO, since their model encourages object-related queries: "greendao is an ORM-framework. This means it maps your table-rows to object." -- [Select multiple columns from two tables using greendao](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26250365/select-multiple-columns-from-two-tables-using-greendao)